# Jquery - Each function to check class name input filled or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

Used below HTML/JS to check whether all input fields with '.firstname' and '.lastname' are filled or not. if not filled, get 'data-firstname' or 'data-lastname' attribute element of that input field and display in error msg.

It works some way correctly. Some time it breaks and validation part on working correctly. Not sure where its getting missed out.

Need some solution to solve this issue Please.

Thanks

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="passenger-name">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 campaign-firstname form-validate">
        <div class="form-title">Given name</div>
        <input class="name-validator firstname" type="text" name="First Name" data-firstname="Given name is missing">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 campaign-lastname form-validate">
        <div class="form-title">Family name</div>
        <input class="name-validator lastname" type="text" name="Last Name" data-lastname="Family name is missing">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 remove-flight" style="display: none"><a href="javascript:void(0);" aria-label="Remove"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="add-more--names">
    <div class="passenger-name row-names">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 campaign-firstname form-validate">
        <div class="form-title">Given name</div>
        <input class="name-validator firstname" type="text" name="First Name" data-firstname="Given name is missing">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 campaign-lastname form-validate">
        <div class="form-title">Family name</div>
        <input class="name-validator lastname" type="text" name="Last Name" data-lastname="Family name is missing">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 remove-flight" style="display: block;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" aria-label="Remove"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="passenger-name row-names">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 campaign-firstname form-validate">
        <div class="form-title">Given name</div>
        <input class="name-validator firstname" type="text" name="First Name" data-firstname="Given name is missing">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 campaign-lastname form-validate">
        <div class="form-title">Family name</div>
        <input class="name-validator lastname" type="text" name="Last Name" data-lastname="Family name is missing">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 remove-flight" style="display: block;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" aria-label="Remove"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**JS:**

```
  $('#campaign-btn').click(function(){
    $('.name-validator.firstname').each(function(){
      var $CampFirstNameValidate = $('.campaign-firstname .name-validator');
      if($(this).val() == ''){
        let $campaginFirstNameValidate:any = $CampFirstNameValidate.attr('data-firstname');
        $campaginError.push($campaginFirstNameValidate);
        $CampFirstNameValidate.addClass('has-error');
        $CampFirstNameValidate.parent().find('.form-title').addClass('has-error');
      } else {
        $CampFirstNameValidate.removeClass('has-error');
        $CampFirstNameValidate.parent().find('.form-title').removeClass('has-error');
      }
    });

    $('.name-validator.lastname').each(function(){
      var $CampLastNameValidate = $('.campaign-lastname .name-validator');
      if($(this).val() == ''){
        let $campaginLastNameValidate:any = $CampLastNameValidate.attr('data-lastname');
        $campaginError.push($campaginLastNameValidate);
        $CampLastNameValidate.addClass('has-error');
        $CampLastNameValidate.parent().find('.form-title').addClass('has-error');
      } else {
        $CampLastNameValidate.removeClass('has-error');
        $CampLastNameValidate.parent().find('.form-title').removeClass('has-error');
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some selector issues in your `script`. Try the following:

```js
$('#campaign-btn').click(function(){
    let $campaginError = [];
    $('.name-validator.firstname').each(function(){
      var $CampFirstNameValidate = $('.campaign-firstname>.name-validator');
      if($(this).val() == ''){
        let $campaginFirstNameValidate = $CampFirstNameValidate.attr('data-firstname');
        $campaginError.push($campaginFirstNameValidate);
        $CampFirstNameValidate.addClass('has-error');
        $CampFirstNameValidate.parent().find('.form-title').addClass('has-error');
      } else {
        $CampFirstNameValidate.removeClass('has-error');
        $CampFirstNameValidate.parent().find('.form-title').removeClass('has-error');
      }
    });

    $('.name-validator.lastname').each(function(){
      var $CampLastNameValidate = $('.campaign-lastname>.name-validator');
      if($(this).val() == ''){
        let $campaginLastNameValidate = $CampLastNameValidate.attr('data-lastname');
        $campaginError.push($campaginLastNameValidate);
        $CampLastNameValidate.addClass('has-error');
        $CampLastNameValidate.parent().find('.form-title').addClass('has-error');
      } else {
        $CampLastNameValidate.removeClass('has-error');
        $CampLastNameValidate.parent().find('.form-title').removeClass('has-error');
      }
    });
    console.log($campaginError);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="passenger-name">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 campaign-firstname form-validate">
      <div class="form-title">Given name</div>
      <input class="name-validator firstname" type="text" name="First Name" data-firstname="Given name is missing">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 campaign-lastname form-validate">
      <div class="form-title">Family name</div>
      <input class="name-validator lastname" type="text" name="Last Name" data-lastname="Family name is missing">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 remove-flight" style="display: none"><a href="javascript:void(0);" aria-label="Remove"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="add-more--names">
  <div class="passenger-name row-names">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 campaign-firstname form-validate">
      <div class="form-title">Given name</div>
      <input class="name-validator firstname" type="text" name="First Name" data-firstname="Given name is missing">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 campaign-lastname form-validate">
      <div class="form-title">Family name</div>
      <input class="name-validator lastname" type="text" name="Last Name" data-lastname="Family name is missing">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 remove-flight" style="display: block;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" aria-label="Remove"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="passenger-name row-names">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 campaign-firstname form-validate">
      <div class="form-title">Given name</div>
      <input class="name-validator firstname" type="text" name="First Name" data-firstname="Given name is missing">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 campaign-lastname form-validate">
      <div class="form-title">Family name</div>
      <input class="name-validator lastname" type="text" name="Last Name" data-lastname="Family name is missing">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 remove-flight" style="display: block;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" aria-label="Remove"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
  </div>
</div><br>
<input type="button" id="campaign-btn" value="Submit"/>
```

Comment: Hi Mamun, Thanks a lot for your code.. Almost there. But, when i entered value on 2nd 'firstname' and 'lastname' and submit. It removes 'has-error' in all available fields. Is it possible to remove only on entered fields. Empty feilds not remove 'has-error' class name.  Thanks

Comment: @TDG, I didn't change any logic from your code. I just change `$('.campaign-firstname .name-validator')` and `$campaginFirstNameValidate:any`.